# jQuery SlideShow of Reviews if Class Exists

Tags: jquery, slideshow, slide

I have dynamically created Reviews inside Tables with class 'helpfulreviews'.  I want to take these Tables and essentially hide all but one of them and automatically slide into the next table after a certain period of time using jQuery

Here are Three Reviews, I want one to display and slide into the other after around 10 seconds, then slide into the third review, then rotate back to beginning.  I have simplified the example:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="helpfulreviews">
  <tbody>
     <tr> 
        <td>MY FIRST REVIEW GOES HERE<br>Terrible Product</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="helpfulreviews">
  <tbody>
     <tr> 
        <td>MY SECOND REVIEW GOES HERE<br>Great Product you have here</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="helpfulreviews">
  <tbody>
     <tr> 
        <td>MY THIRD REVIEW GOES HERE<br>This is an awesome product</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Full code of one of the tables:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="helpfulreviews">
        <tbody><tr> 
          <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="99%"> 
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="colors_descriptionbox">
              <tbody><tr> 
                <td width="1px" valign="top"><img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/90/images/RBox_Border_Left_Top.gif"></td>
                <td width="100%" valign="top" background="/v/vspfiles/templates/90/images/DBox_Border_Top.gif"><img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/90/images/clear1x1.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
                <td width="1px" valign="top"><img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/90/images/DBox_Border_Right_Top.gif"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr> 
                <td width="1px" background="/v/vspfiles/templates/90/images/DBox_Border_Left.gif"><img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/90/images/clear1x1.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
                <td width="100%" valign="top"> 
                  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tbody><tr> 
                      <td><b><img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/90/images/star5.gif"><br> 
                        Great Product</b> </td>
                      <td align="right"><i>April 28, 2011</i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td><i><span class="PageText_L510n">Reviewer</span>: 
                        <span class="PageText_L512n">Anonymous Person</span>

                        </i><br><br></td>
                      <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody></table>
                  I used this product and it was great<br>
                  <br>
                  <span class="PageText_L514n"><span id="helpful"></span></span> <a href="/reviewhelpful.asp?ProductCode=TRU%2DGDM49&amp;ID=12&amp;yes=yes"><img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/90/images/buttons/btn_reviews_yes.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0"></a> 
                  <a href="/reviewhelpful.asp?ProductCode=TRU%2DGDM49&amp;ID=12&amp;yes=no"><img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/90/images/buttons/btn_reviews_no.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0"></a> 

                </td>
                <td width="1px" background="/v/vspfiles/templates/90/images/DBox_Border_Right.gif"><img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/90/images/clear1x1.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
              </tr><tr> 
                <td width="1px" valign="top"><img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/90/images/DBox_Border_Left_Bottom.gif"></td>
                <td width="100%" valign="top" background="/v/vspfiles/templates/90/images/DBox_Border_Bottom.gif"><img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/90/images/clear1x1.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
                <td width="1px" valign="top"><img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/90/images/DBox_Border_Right_Bottom.gif"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody></table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Does your helpfulreviews class have anything important in it? (I'm messing around with your code and i want to include it if it's important) If so can you post it please?

Comment: @Thomas-Shields Yes my helpfulreviews class has many things inside, I have updated code above!

Comment: Great question btw.  Finally got my answer up, and learned a lot in making it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. Here's a working example. Obviously you can tweak the sizes and stuff to fit your purpose. The idea is to wrap the tables in a container div with `overflow:hidden` and offset them as needed (i.e, the first table is positioned to fill the div, the second has `margin-left` equal to the width of the container, the third's margin left is twice the width, etc.)

```
 <style type="text/css">
 .helpfulreviews
 {
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
       position:absolute; 
 }
 </style>
 <div style="width:400px; height:50px; overflow:hidden; position:relative;" id="sliderContain">
 <table width="100%" height="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="helpfulreviews">
   <tbody>
        <tr>
                 <td>MY FIRST REVIEW GOES HERE<br>Terrible Product</td>
                      </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="helpfulreviews" >  
                        <tbody>  
                           <tr>     
                               <td>MY SECOND REVIEW GOES HERE<br>Great Product you have here</td>   
                                 </tr> 
                                  </tbody></table>
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="helpfulreviews" >  <tbody>     <tr>         <td>MY THIRD REVIEW GOES HERE<br>This is an awesome product</td>     </tr>  </tbody></table>
 </div>
 <script type="text/ecmascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         var w = 300; //set your width here
         var h = 50; //set your height here
         var d = 3000;  //set your delay here
         var n = $(".helpfulreviews").length;
         if(n>1){
          var t = window.setTimeout(slideTable, d);
          $("#sliderContain").css("width", w + "px");
          $("#sliderContain").css("height", h + "px");
          var i = h;
          $(".helpfulreviews").each(function (index) {
              i = h * index;
              $(this).css("top", i + "px");
          });
         }
         function slideTable() {
             $(".helpfulreviews").each(function (index) {
                 if ($(this).css("top") == (1 - n) * h + "px") { //checks if we need to cycle them around
                     $(this).css("top", h + "px");
                 }
             });
             var a2l = "-=" + h + "px";
             $(".helpfulreviews").animate({
                 top: a2l
             }, 300, function () {
                 slideTable();
             }).delay(d);
         };
     });
 </script>
```

EDIT: I changed the code to dynamically change the tables and values and stuff based on defining a few variables; that way you don't have to go through and change a bunch of values everytime you change the size of your reviews.

Comment: VERY NICE.  I am trying to get it work correctly with what I have [HERE](http://v725959.htrhdfbkcym2.demo6.volusion.com/True_GDM_49_2_Door_Merchandiser_Refrigerator_p/tru-gdm49.htm).  The tables will be dynamically created, so I cant specify how many tables there will be.  You will notice the reviews on the right hand side.

Comment: Oh, on second thought, you shouldn't have to specify the number of tables... as long as they have the `.helpfulreviews` class i should be able to count them from jQuery. There. Updated - hope that helps.

Comment: awesome can i get it to go from bottom to top instead of right to left?

Comment: Yeah, by swapping out margin left for margin top. One minute and i'll update it.

Comment: Heck, this is harder than i thought.  The problem is that `table`s are block elements and thus create their own line break, so it's difficult to make margin-top work on them.

Comment: Yeah I am having the same issue, its like offsetting the tables

Comment: Scratch my last comment; it's because margin-top is getting set relative to the previous `div` instead of to the parent. there's gotta be a way to fix that.

Comment: Could someone whack my upsdie the head for being an absolute moron? `top` is just what we need and my mind just completely blanked. I'm updating the code...

Comment: lol awesome, I will check it out.  I haven't been able to get it working on my end correctly.

Comment: Wow nice.  I am still having a minor issue with my wrapper id. I cant set a height on the 'sliderContain' div because each review may be longer than the previous.  Can I get it to where it changes based on the height of the '.helpfulreviews' it is currently displaying?

Comment: Hm. Making the height dynamic wouldn't work because that would mess up the whole sliding system. Not sure that would work... can't you just make the `#sliderContain` div really tall? For longer divs, it'd fit nicely, but for shorter divs, there'd just be some empty space at the bottom... does that cause problems?

Comment: Yeah It just isnt working correctly no matter what widths I set.  [SEE IT HERE](http://v725959.htrhdfbkcym2.demo6.volusion.com/True_GDM_49_2_Door_Merchandiser_Refrigerator_p/tru-gdm49.htm)

Comment: widths? why does width matter?

Comment: I see your problem. You need to have the review tables set to `position:absolute` and the containing div set to `position:relative` as in the answer above.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question..widths do not really matter in this situation.  I also updated the positions as instructed.  I almost have it; If I could just get them to vertically align with the top of the wrapping div it would be golden.

Comment: I got it, I had to remove the height from the class 'helpfulreviews', thanks so much!

Comment: @Thomas Shields So another dilemma, It will not appear when I try an set an IF statement on it for `if ($(".helpfulreviews").length > 1){`

Comment: Debug says SlideTable is not Defined?

Comment: probably because (looking at your code) you accidently copied the first 4 lines of my answer into a section script block (thus trying to call a function that wasn't there). Check out line 382.

Comment: I have started over from scratch, I have added the working code right before the `</body>`.  Now when I put an if statement in, they will not appear.

Comment: Yes your correct, it works fine if there is MORE than one table with class 'helpfulreviews'.  However, if there is only 1 table with class 'helpfulreviews' it does not work.  [CLICK HERE TO SEE ONE REVIEW EXAMPLE](http://v725959.htrhdfbkcym2.demo6.volusion.com/product_p/war-wpm60.htm)  This is why I would like to add an If .helpfulreviews > 1 do slide else `$('#allreviewstop').attr('style', 'overflow:visible');`

Comment: Oh, i see. It works fine for me.... I edited the answer, wrapping the initiatory `setTimeout` in an `if(n>1)`

Comment: Perfect, had to add my ELSE statement in and it worked great!  Thanks again!